# @OneToMany mapping and creating JOIN table with same type entities fails with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an `Employee` class. A `Worker` class extends `Employee`, and `Leader` class extends `Worker`.

Every `Leader` has a list `public List workersResponsibleFor = new ArrayList<>();`. I want to create a Join table, to illustrate if a `Leader` is responsible for one or many `Workers`.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="EMP_TYPE")
@Table(name="EMPLOYEES")
public abstract class Employee implements Printable, Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "employee_id", unique = true)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "position")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Position position;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "salary")
    private Double salary;

    @Transient
    public List<Project> projectsWorkingOn = new ArrayList<>();

    public Employee() {
    }
}
```

`Worker`:

```
@Entity
public class Worker extends Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "worker_id", unique = true)
    private int id;

    public Worker() {
    }
}
```

`Leader`:

```
@Entity
public abstract class Leader extends Worker {

    public Leader() {
    }

    public Leader(Position position, String name, Double salary) {
        super(position, name, salary);
    }

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name="WORKERS_RESPONSIBLE_FOR",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="responsible_for")})
    public List<Worker> workersResponsibleFor = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I'm sure, that the List annotations in the `Leader` class are wrong, because I got a lot of errors every time I try to make it work. How can I annotate it properly, to collect the responsibilities into a new junction table?

Comment: one thing that is "wrong" is adding more `@Id` fields in subclasses of the original base class (which defined the PK). Other than that ... why not post "lots of errors"

Comment: Why are you using a join table for a one-to-many relationship?

Comment: His use of join table is irrelevant to the problem. You can use join table or FK; he chose join table. Both should work